# AngularJS routing to a different template based on Ajax results

Tags: angularjs, ajax

I've got an AngularJS 1.4.1 site, and I have a situation where I need to use different templates based on an ajax call. When I route to a specific URL; say:

```
www.site.com/#/tournament/1
```

I want AngularJS to look up information about tournament 1 in the database and pick a template based on the value, notably which type of tournament it is. The closest I've come is to make the ngroute into a function, like so;

```
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/test/:id', {
            templateUrl : function($routeProvider){
                    $.get("/tournament_details/tournament_details.php?t_id="+$routeProvider.id, function(data)
                    {
                        if(data[0].tournament_type == 1)
                            return "tournament_type1.html";
                        else
                            return "tournament_type2.html";
                    }
                );
            }
        })
```

But it isn't working. It never returns a template and I simply get a blank page and no exceptions are thrown. I'm guessing it isn't waiting for the ajax promise properly?

I have "solved" the solution by creating directives for each tournament type that returns the correct templateUrl, and in the tournament info page made it as per:

```
<tournamentType1 ng-if="type==1"/>
<tournamentType2 ng-if="type==2"/>
```

And then do the ajaxcall in the controller. It works fine, but I'd much prefer a solution that scales better as I add more tournament types. (is it a "better" solution by placing logic in the routing? Maybe not, but it's fun to think about)

Comment: can you add `/:type` in url? Then use `$routeParams` to return the template string?

Comment: There are several issues:
#1 You never return anything. Your return statements are inside an anonymous function and not inside the templateUrl function.
#2 Your templateUrl function returns before the call is finished, resolving in nothign being retuend. You CAN do this, but you will need to wait for the http-call to finish - which you are not doing right now, so the return value is empty! I suggest you use the $http service in angular and use the $q service to wait for the promise to resolve. This way the call has actually finished by the time you return.

Comment: Valid point on the return there. I initially tried injecting $q and using deferred, but the templateUrl function doesn't accept it. Same with $http. Couldn't wrap my head around it. How would you go about doing that? It works fine in a resolve, but the using the same syntax for templateUrl fails.

Comment: I see. I wasn't aware that those services were not available at the config stage. You could get them directly from the injector: 
var http = angular.injector(['ng']).get('$http'); but thats a hack!

Comment: Awesome hack though! That got me to access http. However, templateUrl doesn't seem to understand promises. It sems to try and access the webpage with the promise object; angular.js:12314 Error: [$compile:tpload] Failed to load template: {} (HTTP status: 404 Not Found). Since it tries with www.site.com/[object%20Object]. I'll keep playing around with it and see if I can get it to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update & Solution:**

Thanks to Silas Hansen help I've been able to access the angular http service in the templateUrl function. However, the promise wasn't executing as expected. Using the route:

```
        templateUrl : function($routeProvider){
           var http = angular.injector(['ng']).get('$http'); 

           var prom = http.get("/tournament_details/tournament_details.php?t_id="+$routeProvider.id)
                .then(function(data)
                {
                    if(data.data[0].tournament_type == 1)
                            return "tournament_type1.html";
                        else
                            return "tournament_type2.html";
                });

                return prom;
        }})
```

You get an exception where it's trying to access www.site.com/[Object%20Object].

I'm guessing the problem is how promises work. Since what's being returned to the templateUrl is a promise object with a listener for when the call is complete, it'll throw an exception since you can't jam a listener into an URL. Makes sense. My solution in the end was to instead use a template returner rather than templateurl and returing a directive that in return points to the appropriate template.

**Solution:**

```
.when('/test/:t_id', {
            template : function($routeProvider){
               var http = angular.injector(['ng']).get('$http'); 

               var prom = http.get("/tournament_details/tournament_details.php?t_id="+$routeProvider.id)
                    .then(function(data)
                    {
                        if(data.data[0].tournament_type == 1)
                            return "<tournament-type-one/>";
                        else
                            return "<tournament-type-two/>";
                    });

                    return prom;
            }})
.directive('tournamentTypeOne',   [function ($scope)
{
    return {
        templateUrl:"tournament_type1.html",
        restrict: 'E'
    };

}])
.directive('tournamentTypeTwo',   [function ($scope)
{
    return {
        templateUrl:"tourament_type2.html",
        restrict: 'E'
    };

}])
```